# How to display succesfull message only when i submit the query?

Tags: php, mysql, submit

It's a simple code but i can't understand where is my mistake. I want to display succesfull message under the form when i click the submit but the message stays there all the time. When i enter in the page where the form is the message is under the form. How to take it out only when the query is succesfull ?

```
<?php
  $posted = false;
  if(isset($_POST['add']))
  {
   $posted = true;
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $rate = $_POST['rate'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $dth = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $q = "INSERT INTO reviews(email, name, rate, comment, date_created) VALUES ('$email', '$name', '$rate', '$comment', '$dth')";
    $k = mysqli_query($con,$q);
    }
 ?>
<body>
<h1>Leave a review</h1>
<div class="error-conteiner">

</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<form action="" method="post" class="form-content">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="field">
            <label>E-mail <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="email" class="required-field" data-validate="email"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="name"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Rate</label>
            <select name="rate">
                <option value=''>Choose rate</option>
                <option value='1'>1</option>
                <option value='2'>2</option>
                <option value='3'>3</option>
                <option value='4'>4</option>
                <option value='5'>5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        <label>Comment <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <textarea name="comment" class="comment required-field"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn" name="add" />

</form>
<?php
    if($posted){
    if($k)
    echo "Thank you for your comment!";

 else
    die(mysqli_error());
 }

 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You know you have no connection statements here, right?... and you would normally submit a date_created from a form. That would normally be a value set automatically in the db. Apart from that this code is fine (ignoring the lack of prepared statements)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not professional and nice solution, but works well, if you make a query after the post with ex. $email and $name or other parameters. If the result is not empty, then you can put the results or just a simple message also into the output.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<?php
    if($posted){
    if($k)
        echo "Thank you for your comment!";

     else
    die(mysqli_error());
 }

 ?>
```

with

```
<?php
if($posted===true){
    if($k) echo "Thank you for your comment!";
     else die(mysqli_error());
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to put {} after your first if

Answer (score 0):

Directly below:

```
$k = mysqli_query($con,$q);
```

add:

```
if(!$k) {
    die(mysqli_error());
}
```

If the query wasn't executed, for whatever reason, show the error and stop.
You might consider adding a development mode variable or constant, because the mysqli_error() message is only valuable for the developer and the content is not for your users eyes. Anyway:

---

Replace:

```
<?php
    if($posted){
    if($k)
        echo "Thank you for your comment!";

     else
    die(mysqli_error());
 }    
?>
```

with:

```
if($posted === true) {
    echo 'Thank you for your comment!';
}
```

The mysql error is handled, where it occurs. 
The success message is only displayed, when successfully send.

It's also possible to make a header redirection on success. But that depends, on what you like.

```
if($posted === true) {
    header('Location: success-message-page.php');
    exit;         
}
```